# How can I programmatically tell, in JavaScript, from which file a particular CSS class is getting applied to an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, css, mootools

I need to know how to use JavaScript to find out from which file a particular CSS class is getting applied to a HTML element.

I am developing a web application where user can change the CSS property of particular element, just like we can change it in Firebug.

**Edit:** I need the JavaScript code of Firebug which shows CSS in right pane in HTML tab with link to files which has that class.

Comment: Look in the firebug source. Good luck, that code isn't so easy to understand. http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.7

Comment: The glib answer is that "It will always be 'none'", since there is no such thing as a "css class". CSS has rule sets. Some of them might have a class selector attached. Classes themselves, however, are an HTML concept.

Comment: any way to get that class 'with the rule sets described' coming from which file(if it is external, which will be the case in my web application), tried looking into firebug code, but it will be a time consuming process , will go last to it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle) method returns a [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration).  Look at the parentRule property of that to get to the [cssRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/cssRule), that has a [parentStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/cssRule.parentStyleSheet) property which should give you the information you need.

The [Firebug Lite code](https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js) might be a less confusing place to look than the full extension to get an idea of how it's all supposed to fit together.

Comment: the properties mentioned doesn't helped, but the URL did, After a small digging it looks like that, particular information I need is not stored in any of the browser objects, and i need to maintain a cache of all the rules with the file name mapped to it. Looks like firebug is also doing the same..